# How to copy CMD Console Output to file after running command

Tags: shell, powershell, console, output

Consider Example as: `C:\Users>help`

Output: We get list of commands for working with CMD

Expected: I want once this command is run - whatever is present in cmd console, I want to paste in some notepad file through some command (Not by Marking and Pasting).

Comment: Why do you need to do it?

Comment: @Bill_Stewart - I have a tool which generates OTP. And I need to capture that OTP in some file. Redirection operator does not support with that tool.

Answer (score 3):

For PowerShell, you can use `Start-Transcript`, it will save the all console output to a file.

From the documentation:

> The Start-Transcript cmdlet creates a record of all or part of a
>   Windows PowerShell session to a text file. The transcript includes all
>   command that the user types and all output that appears on the
>   console.

Reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.host/start-transcript

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
C:\Users>help > help.txt
```

results will be in `help.txt`

Comment: I am lookingn where, once i ran help and gets output. Then whatever is present in console - I want to paste in notepad file through command.

Comment: @Poc can you explain why the above solution is not working for you? you can open `help.txt` with `notepad` and it will contain the result of the `help` ....

Comment: the command help > help.txt will work. But here you are trying to run help command and simultaneously pasting the output to help.txt.

Comment: i want that- once i run my command and gets output shown in console. Is there any command which can paste entire visible output in console to some file .

Comment: @Poc I don't think that what you are looking for exists. However I could suggest a workaround. Enable telnet server. telnet to self. use telnet -f filename.txt . Then what ever you do in console will be saved into file...

Answer (score 0):

You can also use ctrl + A to select all, ctrl + C to copy, then use ctrl + v to paste into notepad.